# Customize paranoid in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am working in an old database, and the old programmer did a soft delete with bool field, if `field` set as 0 then is not deleted, else he is; so I wanna integrate this database with a paranoid sequelize system, but I can't find some way to change `deletedAt` type to BOOLEAN, there some way? or I need to implement this. in the doc the only thing I can change is the `deletedAt` field name.

[image]

Comment: please change `deletedAt` as DATE type

Comment: i cant change the schema :(

Comment: @CaioFilus Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, i have read the sequelize code, and it doenst have support for boolean softdelete :(, maybe creating a branch of sequelize and propose a change, this came be possible